# why cannot the "for" loop to get the value from the list?

Tags: python, for-loop

when I use "rb = random.choice(myList) and bFont", it's function.
then I use "for i in range(len(myList)) and bFont" and click,
it cannot loop, just display a fix list value, why?

```
import pygame
import random
import re
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
size = (1280, 580)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("1")
bg = pygame.image.load("b")
white = (0, 0, 0)
black = (230, 0, 100)
light_grey = (224, 224, 224)
dark_grey = (200, 200, 200)
text = pygame.font.SysFont("Agency FB", 20)
myList = ["a5一个5ˈei", "am5是5æm", "are5是5a:r"]
font = pygame.font.Font('./simhei.ttf', 25)
button_text = font.render("aaaaa", True, black)
button_rect = pygame.Rect(70, 350, 200, 200)
bFont = None
var = True
while var:
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            var = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):


                for i in range(len(myList)):
                #rb = random.choice(myList)
                    bFont = font.render(myList[i], True, white)
                    bFont1 = font.render(myList[i], True, white)
                #bFont = font.render(rb, True, white)
                #bFont1 = font.render(rb, True, white)

                
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    if button_rect.collidepoint(mouse):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, dark_grey, (70, 350, 200, 200), 0)
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, (70, 350, 200, 200), 0)
    screen.blit(button_text, (90, 450))
    if bFont:
        screen.blit(bFont, (70, 100))
        screen.blit(bFont1, (70, 220))
    pygame.display.update()
```

\help me
\help

Comment: The value of `range(len(myList)) and bFont` is just `bFont`, so that's equivalent to `for i in bFont`

Comment: What are you expecting `for i in range(len(myList)) and bFont` to do?

Comment: if bFont:
        screen.blit(bFont, (70, 100))
        screen.blit(bFont1, (70, 220))

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: I tried "for item in list:", it's not function.

Comment: In this case it would be `for item in myList:`. Then you do `bFont = font.render(item, True, white)`

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to do by adding `and bFont` in these places. `and` is a logical operator, it's usually used in `if` conditions.

Comment: I didn't use 'and' in my code

Comment: I thought that's what you're asking about. You want to know why `for i in range(len(myList)) and bFont:` doesn't work.

Comment: when I use "rb = random.choice(myList)", it's working; then I change to "for ...", it's  abnormal.

Comment: It's really hard to understand the question because you have all those comments with code that doesn't work. Post the code you're trying to execute, not the working code with comments. You also need to explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The `screen.blit()` call isn't inside the loop. So the value of `bFont` will be the value you assigned on the last iteration of the loop, the other values will be ignored.